# Assign a default description to new terms under a custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, customization, description

When I create a new term for a custom taxonomy, I would like it to be assigned a placeholder description. The description would be the same for all new terms and can be manually changed if I want to replace the placeholder with a custom description.

Unfortunately searching around for a solution hasn't turned up much. Any help in making this work would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options to go solve your concern, one could be:

**First**: you need a custom field to store your placeholder. For that you should use the [add_term_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_term_meta) function.

**Second**: Use [get_term_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_meta/) to retrieve the custom field value.

That's all. If you want customizations you will need to specify a little bit more in order to help. If you're not comfortable coding I recommend you using [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/).